# angular material mdDialog that fit content of an element

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-material, angular-material2

Does anyone know if it is possible with [MdDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) to have the backdrop fitting an HTML element (a div of my page) ?

This feature was previously possible in AngularJS Material with 'parent' property of [$mdDialog's options](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog#mddialog-show-optionsorpreset).

Trying to do the same with Angular material2 (2.0.0-beta.11).

Thanks